# with 'react-router'.browserHistory I get this.props.children == undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I dont understand how browserHistory changes app execution. This is code is WORKING OK:

```
var React = require('react'),
    ReactDOM = require('react-dom'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    Route = Router.Route,
    browserHistory = Router.browserHistory,
    hashHistory = Router.hashHistory;

var Layout = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <SideMenu />
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var routes = (
    <Router.Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}>

            <Route path="auth/startpage" component={require('./startpage')}/>

        </Route>
    </Router.Router>
);
```

This code is working fine but I get hash code to my url. So I just change hashHistory to browserHistory like that:

```
<Router.Router history={browserHistory}>
```

... and after that `{this.props.children}` is *undefined*! No errors. React 0.14.7, react-router 2.0.0. Pleas tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm strange, I can't see anything inherently wrong with your code. Where does it say the error is coming from? Is it this.props.children in render()? or from somewhere else?

You could try restructuring your file. The following works for me using the same version of react-router that you're using:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
ReactDOM.render (( 
 <Router history={browserHistory} />
   // Do Something
 </Router> 
), document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what Matt Bilbow said, I agree it may be more helpful to say something along the lines of:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
```

This way, it makes it more semantic while both writing and reading the code. For example, your resulting code would be similar to:

```
var Layout = React.createClass({

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <SideMenu />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <Route path="auth/startpage" component={require('./startpage')}/>
    </Route>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    {routes}
  </Router>,
  document.body {/*or wherever want it to render from*/}
);
```

You may also want to declare

```
var startPage = require('./startpage')
```

at the top just so the code looks cleaner when you reference it later.